# href is always "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

On alert I always get undefined... why ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr("href"); 
        alert (path);
        $.get(path, function(data) { $("#texte").html(data); });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="pulse/data/blocks/intro.html">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="pulse/data/blocks/presentation.html">presentation</a></li>
    <li><a href="pulse/data/blocks/pourquoi.html">pourquoi ?</a></li>
    <li><a href="pulse/data/blocks/forfaits.html">forfaits</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't $(this) the list item (li), and not the anchor (a)?  If so, "href" isn't an attribute of the li.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to select the `a` tag.

```
var path = $('a', this).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select  element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").click(function() {
        var path = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
        alert (path);
        $.get(path, function(data) { $("#texte").html(data); });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're assigning the click-handler on the LI elements, not the A elements.

This is correct:

```
$("#menu a")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the `href` of your list item (`li`). Change your code to the following:

```
$("#menu ul li a").click(function() {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the `href` attribute of the `li` element. You are probably looking for the `href` attribute on the `a` element instead.  Use this selector instead:

```
$("#menu ul li a")
```

It can probably be reduced by removing either the `ul` or `li` from the selector as well.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that `$(this)` references the `<li>` element instead of it's link. You can fix this by using the following selector:

```
var path = $("a", $(this)).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed a tag.

```
$("#menu ul li a").click
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery is referencing the wrong element: 
Instead of referencing the UL Li element you need to reference the UL LI A element as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu ul li **a**").click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr("href"); 
        alert (path);
        $.get(path, function(data) { $("#texte").html(data); });
        return false;
    });
});
```